# How to use swagger with complex query data type for "get" request in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui

I used swagger to generate document for spring mvc project.
For post request,it is OK.

```
@ApiOperation("post")
@PostMapping("post")
public Map<String, String> post(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

[image]

Now I want to change the HTTP method to get, because it is a query request. However the following code is wrong since GET method has no request body.

```
@ApiOperation("get")
@GetMapping("get")
public Map<String, String> get(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

So I need to change it to

```
@ApiOperation("get")
@GetMapping("get")
public Map<String, String> get(@RequestParam Foo foo) {
    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

However swagger will just show foo as a string, losing date structure.
[image]

so what should I do now?